# Conditional packaging into WSP file?

Tags: packaging

In one of my Visual Studio project, I have two javascript files (both deployed under `Layouts`):

- Mywonderfulscript.js
- Mywonderfulscript.min.js

The latter is the minified version of the former.

I would like to register either of the two depending on the build configuration.

By now I have this code inside my custom web control :

```
    protected ScriptLink scriptLinkRegistration;

    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {

        this.scriptLinkRegistration = new ScriptLink
        {
            Localizable = false,
#if DEBUG
            Name = "pathto/Mywonderfulscript.js"
#else
            Name = "pathto/Mywonderfulscript.min.js"
#endif
        };
        this.Controls.Add(this.scriptLinkRegistration);
     }
```

This is working, but this results in always deploying both files.

Is there any way to conditionally include a file into the resulting WSP file?

If the compilation configuration, include the full script, if not, include the minified script.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative .. you could look at creatig the "Minified JS File" as part of your deployment / build scripts?

This could mean creating your own custom Deployment Configuration (well supported in VS2010 / VS2012).

Doing this you could create the WSP Package, then crack it open and replace the JS file with your new minified JS? (also updating the paths in any of the XML)

Then deploy your WSP using PowerShell?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible without building your own custom Visual Studio extension.

Perhaps you could include a pre-build script which modifies the SPData file to remove the XML reference for your debug file?

You could then use a different script for DEBUG / RELEASE (or any other configurations) and this would also theoretically work in automated build environments too?

Comment: I'm not very fan of this technique, because modifying the spdata files will leads to source control issues

Comment: Agreed .. maybe not suitable for a dev environment (although it would work for automated builds)